How to map key for specific mode map
I have this peace of code :
(use-package flymake
  :ensure t
  :hook (prog-mode . flymake-mode)
  :bind (("C-h ." . display-local-help)
     :map flymake-mode-map
     ("C-c ! n" . flymake-goto-next-error)
     ("C-c ! p" . flymake-goto-prev-error)
     ("C-c ! l" . flymake-show-buffer-diagnostics)))

And wonder what is the corresponding emacs-lisp command for the part

:bind


:map flymake-mode-map


("c-c ! n" . flymake-goto-next-error)


I guest that :

:hook
Correspond to (add-hook) but :bind :map I dont know


I just find that with this fragment it is working ..
(with-eval-after-load 'flymake
  (define-key flymake-mode-map (kbd "C-c ! n") 'flymake-goto-next-error))


